# Are Database Users Stored in Query Store and Can you find the CPU Usage of a Database User in there? (SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, sql-query-store

I'm looking to find the CPU usage of Users in a Database in SQL Server Management Studio, wondered if this kind of information is stored in Query Store?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this kind of information is compiled and stored in a format that you'll easily be able to use.

There are two typical solutions here:

1) If you have a transactional database with predictable queries I'd suggest adding logging triggers storing to your own logging tables.

2) If you have an queryable/interactive database where users are writing their own queries on an ad-hoc basis (most datawarehouses or reporting databases fall into this category) I would suggest looking into the mechanics of who2. It's fairly simple to set up a job to take snapshots of currently running queries periodically (say, once per minute) and then aggregate the results into your own reports. I've done this multiple times in the past and it's always been a solution for multiple problems.

Answer (score 0):

Query Store is not attempting to build a per-user slice of query usage patterns within a single database. It shows aggregated data across time for the whole database.  So "no".  Instead, you should consider looking at XEvents if you really want to track per-user query usage stats.